# parse.com REST API is not returning all of the properties for one of my classes

Tags: rest, parse-platform

I've been using Parse from an iOS app and wanted to fetch some of the data from a web app using the REST API.  Following the docs, I tried this on the command line:

```
url -X GET -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: MYAPPID"   
           -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: MYAPIKEY" 
           -G --data-urlencode 'limit=1' 
           https://api.parse.com/1/classes/MyClass
```

However, it isn't returning properties for all of the columns in my parse app.

What could be happening?  It's possible there is some configuration in Parse, but I can't find it.  There are no special security settings for that table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out myself.  The default query returns the oldest records first.  I believe some columns were added later, and there must be no data in the early records.  When I request the data ordered by most recent first, then I see all of the columns:

url -X GET -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: MYAPPID"
           -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: MYAPIKEY" 
           -G --data-urlencode 'limit=1' 
           --data-urlencode 'order=-createdAt' 
           https://api.parse.com/1/classes/MyClass